# No instance for (Show (IO ())) arising from a use of ‘print’

Tags: haskell

Just for learning I did this on my console WinGHCi:

```
let ls = [putChar 'x',putChar 'y']
```

then if do:

```
head ls
```

the output is obviusly  *x* *(obviusly in the sense that I undestand why)*

else if I do:

```
tail ls
```

I get this error:

> No instance for (Show (IO ())) arising from a use of ‘print’
>
> In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Why? Shouldn't output *y* or `[putChar 'y']`?

Comment: well in the first case `GHCi` knows to execute the `IO` action - in the second case it get's a list of `IO` actions (which are not an instance of `Show`) - you can use `sequence_ $ tail ls` to get something *similar*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behaviour is explained [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html).

`head ls` has type `IO ()` so GCHi executes the action and doesn't print the result `()`.

In contrast, `tail ls` has type `[IO ()]`. Since this is not an `IO` action, GCHi attempts to display it using `print` which has type:

```
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

however since there is no `Show` instance for `[IO ()]` you get the error. If you want to evaluate the actions you can use `sequence_`:

```
sequence_ (tail ls)
```

Answer (score 7):

> then if do: `head ls`
>    the output is obviusly x

well, [actually *not* obviously](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2OmmcsAZnw)! In fact, `head ls` is not something directly related to the character `'x'`. First of all, it's simply an `IO` action, and GHCi assumes that this action does something you want to happen: it has a special treatment that for an `IO` action it tries not to show the action, but *executes* it. Well, good that you didn't consider instead the list [`[launchMissiles, putStrLn "oops"]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-missiles-0.3/docs/Acme-Missiles.html#v:launchMissiles)...

Now, *executing* the action does indeed result in the character `'x'` being printed to the console, which just happens to be also your viewport, so you see it as if it was just the value of `putChar 'x'`. But it's not!

OTOH, `tail ls` is from the outside just a list, so ghci doesn't assume you want anything executed. It does try to *show* the list, but you can't *show* an IO action or anything with IO actions in it; that's what the error message says.

Answer (score 5):

When you have

```
> let ls = [putChar 'x', putChar 'y']
```

you aren't executing the actions stored in that list, you're just constructing those actions, if that makes sense.  You could have something like

```
printHelp :: IO ()
printHelp = putStrLn "You need to pass XYZ options to this program"
```

defined in a file.  This doesn't immediately print out the message, but instead constructs an action that, once executed, prints that message to the console.  Execution happens in one of two places: in the `main` function and in GHCi.

It looks like you're using GHCi to execute code, which is awesome for exploring different functions, but is a bit different than executing code in a file.  Whenever you evaluate an `IO Something` action by itself in GHCi, it runs that IO action.  Whenever you evaluate any other value in GHCi it inserts `print` in front of that line.  So when you do

```
> head ls
```

This has type `IO ()`, and so the action `putChar 'x'` is executed, resulting in `x` being printed out to the console.  When you do

```
> tail ls
```

This has type `[IO ()]`, so GHCi tries to put a `print` in front of it, making it equivalent to

```
> print (tail ls)
```

The `print` function has type

```
print :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

We've passed a list to `print` here, and there is an instance of `Show` for lists, but only when the elements of the list have an instance of `Show`.  So the compiler tries to see if `IO ()` has an instance for `Show`.  Unfortunately, it does not, since `IO` is a pretty complex type that represents that pretty much anything can happen.  So the compiler shows an error that `IO ()` doesn't have an instance for `Show`.

If you want to instead run every action in a list in order, there is a function for that: `Control.Monad.sequence` (or `Control.Monad.sequence_` if you don't care about the result).  This function actually works on all `Monad`s, not just `IO`:

```
> sequence_ (tail ls)
y> sequence_ ls
xy>
```

Comment: Thank's for your explaination. I choose the other just cause was the first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just `tail ls`, if you do `ls` or `init ls` , you will get the same error.

The type of `ls` is:

```
ls :: [IO ()]
```

When you type something in GHCi, it will evaluate the expression and print the result.

In the second case (`ls`), from the type of `ls`, the **returned value** is a list of actions and `GHC` does not know how to show an action of `IO ()`.

In the first case, GHCi evaluates the `IO ()`, which prints x. There is **no returned values** for `IO ()`, so there is nothing to show and no error.