# No instance for Show arising from a use in "main" level

Tags: haskell, pipe

I have a code that reads files and parses using UU.Parsing lib that  returns an abstract sintax tree and shows on the screen.

I received the error message "No instance for Show" in my functions originated in **tokensParserToByteString** and **applyParser** using **parseIO** (of UU.Parsing lib) and inherited signatures until main. I fixed the signatures but my problem is in the **main** function. I added the instance Show in the signature but I have the next compilation error:

```
No instance for (Show (IO J2s)) arising from a use of ‘main’
In the expression: main
When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’
```

The complete error message is:

```
$ cabal build
Building java2scala-1.0...
Preprocessing library java2scala-1.0...
In-place registering java2scala-1.0...
Preprocessing executable 'java2scala' for java2scala-1.0...
Preprocessing executable 'test' for java2scala-1.0...
[5 of 5] Compiling Main             ( test/Main.hs, dist/build/test/test-tmp/Main.o )

test/Main.hs:27:1:
    No instance for (Show (IO J2s)) arising from a use of ‘main’
    In the expression: main
    When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’
```

Some idea, about the problem?

Main module

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Main where

import UU.Parsing
...
import Content

main :: (Show (IO J2s)) => IO()
main = do f <- getLine
      let command = test f
      command

test :: (Show (IO J2s)) => String -> IO()
test "testparser" = testParser
```

Test module

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module J2s.Parser.Test where

import Content
import J2s.Ast.Sintax
import J2s.Parser
import UU.Parsing
...

testParser :: (Show (IO J2s)) => IO()
testParser  = (runSafeIO $ runProxy $ runEitherK $
                contentsRecursive "path/of/my/tests" />/ handlerParser) :: (Show (IO J2s)) => IO()
```

Content module

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Content where

import Control.Monad(forM, liftM)
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, getDirectoryContents)
import System.FilePath ((</>), splitExtension, splitFileName)
import J2s.Parser
import J2s.Ast.Sintax
import UU.Parsing

import Control.Monad (when, unless)
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Safe hiding (readFileS)

import J2s.Scanner.Token
import Text.Show

import UU.Parsing


contentsRecursive
     :: (CheckP p)
     => FilePath -> () -> Producer (ExceptionP p) FilePath SafeIO ()
contentsRecursive path () = loop path
   where
     loop path = do
         contents path () //> \newPath -> do
             respond newPath
             isDir <- tryIO $ doesDirectoryExist newPath
             let isChild = not $ takeFileName newPath `elem` [".", ".."]
             when (isDir && isChild) $ loop newPath


applyParser :: (Proxy p, Show (IO J2s)) => String -> Consumer p B.ByteString IO ()
applyParser path = runIdentityP loop
  where
    loop = do
        bs <- request ()
        let sc = classify  (initPos path) (B8.unpack bs)
        lift $  B8.putStrLn (tokensParserToByteString sc)

tokensParserToByteString :: (Show (IO J2s)) =>  [Token] -> B.ByteString
tokensParserToByteString tokens = B8.pack(show (parseIO pJ2s tokens))


handlerParser :: (CheckP p, Show (IO J2s)) => FilePath -> Session (ExceptionP p) SafeIO ()
handlerParser path = do
    canRead <- tryIO $ fmap readable $ getPermissions path
    isDir   <- tryIO $ doesDirectoryExist path
    isValidExtension <- tryIO $ evaluate ((snd (splitExtension path) == ".java" || snd (splitExtension path) == ".mora") && (snd (splitFileName path) /= "EncodeTest.java") && (snd (splitFileName path) /= "T6302184.java") && (snd (splitFileName path) /= "Unmappable.java"))
    when (not isDir && canRead && isValidExtension) $
        (readFileSP 10240 path >-> try . applyParser) path


readFileSP
:: (CheckP p)
=> Int -> FilePath -> () -> Producer (ExceptionP p) B.ByteString SafeIO ()
readFileSP chunkSize path () =
    bracket id (openFile path ReadMode) hClose $ \handle -> do
        let loop = do
                eof <- tryIO $ hIsEOF handle
                unless eof $ do
                    bs <- tryIO $ B.hGetSome handle chunkSize
                    respond bs
                    loop
        loop
```

Comment: Can you show a complete error message please?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119459/no-instance-for-show-io-arising-from-a-use-of-print) might help.

Comment: AFAIK, `main` must have type `main :: IO()` or `main :: [String] -> IO()`.

Comment: the complete error message is:        > cabal build      
    Building java2scala-1.0...
    Preprocessing library java2scala-1.0...
    In-place registering java2scala-1.0...
    Preprocessing executable 'java2scala' for java2scala-1.0...
    Preprocessing executable 'test' for java2scala-1.0...
    [5 of 5] Compiling Main             ( test/Main.hs, dist/build/test/test-   tmp/Main.o )

test/Main.hs:27:1:
    No instance for (Show (IO J2s)) arising from a use of ‘main’
    In the expression: main
    When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’

Comment: Please edit your question so you can use proper formatting.

Comment: Yeah, edited Thanks! . Problem is resolved :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A signature like `Show (IO J2s) => IO ()` almost never makes sense. What this expresses is basically “provided the universe is crafted such that `IO J2s` has a `Show` instance, I give you an `IO ()` action”. Well, if the universe has that property, then give us `IO ()` action right now. [Keep nasty <del>chips</del>constraints](https://youtu.be/fYiCPmwOV4A?t=44s)!

Constraints only really make sense if you apply them to *type variables*, i.e. if you're writing code that's polymorphic over several different, but not *all* types. (Like with `CheckP p`). But a constraint applied to concrete types does little more than defer type errors.

`IO J2s` *has no `Show` instance*. And it can't have such an instance: this is an *IO action*. It could be a complete subprogram that might execute costly computations, call commercial third-party library code, launch some missiles... and only in the very end return a `J2s` value. How do you expect to pack all the information of something so possibly complex into a simple string?

What possibly does have a `Show` instance is `J2s`. If you're in the `IO` monad anyway and have an `IO J2s` action, you can at any point fetch the `J2s` value from it by monad-binding that action (i.e. *executing* the subprogram) and just showing the `J2s` value. In your case:

```
tokensParserToByteString :: [Token] -> IO B.ByteString
tokensParserToByteString tokens = fmap (B8.pack . show) $ parseIO pJ2s tokens
```

I case you're confused about fmapping in the IO functor, this is equivalent to

```
tokensParserToByteString :: [Token] -> IO B.ByteString
tokensParserToByteString tokens = do
     j2sValue <- parseIO pJ2s tokens
     return . B8.pack $ show j2sValue
```

Of course you then need to adapt `applyParser` because `tokensParserToByteString` is now an `IO` action. Easy enough with the [`=<<` operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-61--60--60-):

```
applyParser :: Proxy p => String -> Consumer p B.ByteString IO ()
applyParser path = runIdentityP loop
  where
    loop = do
        bs <- request ()
        let sc = classify  (initPos path) (B8.unpack bs)
        lift $ B8.putStrLn =<< tokensParserToByteString sc
```