# Monads for Functional Programming, 2.2 Variation one: Exceptions

Tags: haskell

I've been working on understanding Monads in Haskell a bit better so I've started reading Philip Wadler's paper [Monads for functional programming](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf). In order to internalize the principles a bit better, and expose myself to as much Haskell code as possible, I decided I would code up and test all the examples as I go through the paper.

Right off **2.2 Variation one: Exceptions** is giving me a little trouble. Here is my code.

```
data Term = Con Int | Div Term Term
data M a = Raise Exception | Return a
type Exception = String

answer, error_ :: Term
answer = (Div (Div (Con 1972) (Con 2)) (Con 23))
error_ = (Div (Con 1) (Con 0))

eval :: Term -> M Int
eval (Con a) = Return a
eval (Div t u) = case eval t of 
                    Raise e -> Raise e
                    Return a ->
                        case eval u of 
                            Raise e -> Raise e
                            Return b ->
                                if  b == 0 
                                    then Raise "divide by zero"
                                    else Return (a `div` b)
```

I can load the code into GHCi, but when I try to run

```
eval answer
```

it throws the error

```
No instance for (Show (M Int)) arising from a use of ‘print’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119750/7613834) post which explains why ‘print’ is being called and concluded that maybe I needed to add an instance to Show for M a. But when I added

```
instance Show (M a) where
show (M a) = show a
```

to my code I tried to reload the file I got this error.

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘M’
```

This confused me at first but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18205862/7613834) post explains that I was defining a type constructor not a data constructor.

Anyway, I feel like I am going down a rabbit hole that may or may not have the solution and I figured I'd post the question over here. My code looks to be line-for-line the same as his code. What changes do I need to make to make the code run in GHCi?

Comment: There is no data constructor `M`, only `Raise` and `Return`, so you will need to implement those two cases.

Comment: Another reason to use the `deriving` mechanism - other than saving writing code - is that Haskell will generate an instance that properly handles precedence and nesting of data. So something like `show (Return (Con 4))` will properly result in the string `"Return (Con 4)"` rather than `"Return Con 4"` (assuming a proper `Show` instance for `Term`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The added `Show` instance will not work for two reasons:

1. there is no constraint that says that the `a` of `M a` is an instance of `Show`; and
2. the `M` data type has no data constructor `M`, it has a `Raise`, and a `Return`.

So a straightforward implementation would look like:

```
instance Show a => Show (M a) where
    show (Raise a) = "Raise " ++ show a
    show (Return a) = "Return " ++ show a
```

But we can save us the trouble, and let Haskell automatically derive an instance for `Show` with:

```
data M a = Raise Exception | Return a deriving Show
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. The deriving tool is pretty slick, but I can see why you might want to have custom implementations. For example, it might make sense for the `show (Return a)` to just be just `show a`, and have the `show (Raise a)` case to be `"Exception: " ++ show a`, or something.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it manually, you have to do something like

```
instance (Show a) => Show (M a) where
    show (Raise e)  = "Raise " ++ show e
    show (Return a) = "Return " ++ show a
```

Your type (`M a`) has two data constructors, `Raise` and `Return`.

The easy solution is to just say

```
data M a = Raise Exception | Return a
    deriving (Show)
```

Alternatively you can also manually deconstruct `M a` values every time you want to inspect them in ghci:

```
case eval answer of { Raise e -> "An error occurred: " ++ e; Return x -> show x }
-- instead of 'eval answer'
```

But that gets annoying quickly.